# Only two digits are saving after dot in double value in Laravel 5 and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, double

I am trying to save a double value in MySQl database with Laravel. But only two digits after the dot are saving. I have 5 digits after the dot. For example, my value is 0.01197. But when I saved in database, it only shows 0.01. Rest of the digits are not saved.

I am using Laravel 5.6 with PHP 7.1.2 and MariaDB 10.1.29 version. Here is my DB migration code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('earnings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('content_id');
            $table->foreign('content_id')->references('id')->on('contents');
          //this is the line for saving double value
            $table->double('income_in_usd', 10, 2);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Here is the controller code for saving the value into DB:

```
$earning_id = DB::table('earnings')->insertGetID([
                                'month' => $request->month,
                                //here I am saving my double values
                                'income_in_usd' => $value['net_revenue'],
                                'exchange_rate' => $request->exchange_rate,
                                'income_in_bdt' =>  $value['net_revenue'] * $request->exchange_rate,
                                'content_id' => $content->id,
                            ]);
```

I have tried changing the table column type into float and decimal. But it did not work. Can anyone please find the problem here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try: `$table->double('income_in_usd', 10, 8);` 8 is showing to store 8 digits after dot. You may change it as per your requirement. Hope this will fixed it!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got the problem and solved it.

Comment: You are welcome! I know you got the solution as my comment posted 2 days ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In laravel :

**DOUBLE equivalent with precision, 10 digits in total and 2 after the decimal point.**

So change your migration file like:

```
$table->double('income_in_usd', 10, 5);
```

Comment: Yup..I just got it now. Thanks for your quick answer.